# Laptop unable to access internet ~meter away from router but has full wifi bars throughout the house

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

If I go two stories down from my router to the basement, my laptop shows the full five wifi bars in the system tray as it should, but I can't access web pages. Even if I am in the same room as the router, I can't access web pages > 1 meter away from the router. If I ping 8.8.8.8 from the command prompt I end up with a 100% loss rate (assuming I'm > 1 meter away from the router). I have an xfinity router, but I'm not sure it is the issue because another laptop in my house can connect just fine from far away, so I assume it has something to do with my laptop. It's really weird because even within 1 meter of the router I can only connect to some websites. I can connect to this website, Speedtest, Google, and YouTube, but I can't connect to Imgur, Twitter, or even my router's configuration panel (even if I'm plugged into it directly).

It's really weird because I was on the router's configuration panel earlier, ended up rebooting it (unplugging it and plugging it back in) after I didn't see any sort of oddity on the router's configuration panel, and ever since have not been able to get back onto the configuration panel. The issue where I could only connect within a meter was happening before I rebooted the router though. Clicking the network icon in the system tray shows that I'm currently hooked up to "Network: No internet access" as well as my current wifi/ethernet connection (I tried them both). It is displayed even if everything but my ethernet / wifi card are disabled in the control panel. What in the world is going on with this laptop?

Comment: What OS on the problem lappy?

Comment: Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I would try another router just rule out that hardware.